# How to plot 2 maps in 1 plot using Matplotlib? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to overlay 1 map on another, but I could not.

```
input_file = "slicedSmoothedStokesPlanck/Smoothed_Sliced_PSI_MAP.fits"
i_file = "slicedSmoothedStokesPlanck/Smoothed_Sliced_I_MAP.fits"
pl_b = fits.getdata(input_file, ext=0)
i_file_data = fits.getdata(i_file, ext=0)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) #, projection=wcs
im = ax.imshow(texture, alpha=0.5) #, cmap='RdYlBu_r'
ax.imshow(i_file_data)
plt.title("TEST")
plt.show()
```

The above code, only shows last `ax.imshow(i_file_data)`

The idea is that I have a map1, and map2. I want to overlay map2 with `alpha = 0.5` on map1, and plot it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly then this should work. I assume your bottom layer has color and top layer has just boundaries.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize(8, 8))
pl_b.plot(ax = ax, cmap = "RdYlBu_r", edgecolor = "black", lw = 0.1) #, this is your map 1
i_file_data.plot(ax = ax, facecolor = "none", edgecolor = "black", lw = 0.1, alpha = 0.5) #, this is your map 2
plt.title("TEST")
plt.show()
```

You can tweak the top layer and change the opacity accordingly.
If you want your map 2 be just the outline on top of map 1 then set facecolor = "none" in the second layer